# How can I read line of input without making TeX think it is at the start of a line?

Tags: tex-core

Normally, `\errmessage`, `\immediate\write` etc. starts a newline if there's an incomplete line on the terminal.

```
pdftex '\message{123}\errmessage{hello}\end'
```

Output:

```
entering extended mode
123
! hello.
<*> \message{123}\errmessage{hello}
                                   \end
```

Nevertheless, TeX assumes the terminal input and output is not redirected (probably), so in this case the `!` is not on a separate line.

```
echo 123 | pdftex '\message{123}\read -1 to \aaa\errmessage{hello}\end'
```

Output:

```
entering extended mode
123! hello.
<*> \message{123}\read -1 to \aaa\errmessage{hello}
                                                   \end
?
```

Is there a way to fix the issue to force `!` to appear on a new line? (maybe modify `\read` or something to allow reading?)

Note that the issue may happen even without `\message`:

```
echo 123 | pdftex '\input expl3-generic.tex\read -1 to \aaa\errmessage{hello}\end'
```

Output:

```
entering extended mode
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-generic.tex (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def))! hello.
<*> \input expl3-generic.tex\read -1 to \aaa\errmessage{hello}
                                                              \end
?
```

One possible way to fix the issue is to `\immediate\write 128 {}` after every `\read`, but if a lot of `\read` occurs without any error message etc. it will print lots of spurious lines. And `\message{}` does not do anything.

Comment: Trying to understand your query, I observe that one can do `pdftex '\read -1 to \aaa'` and pdfTeX waits for RET terminated input and then proceeds, but trying `echo aaa | pdftex '\read -1 to \aaa'` generates an error with last output being `!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!`. So it is hard to investigate your question.

Comment: @user691586 The second issue is because pdftex sees the end of the file and start reading from stdin (for which there's nothing). If you add `\end` after the command it wouldn't give an error.

Comment: Is the question about reading a line of input, or is it simply about `\errmessage` not properly starting a new line? Because it looks like the latter is arguably a bug in the (web2c/miktex/whatever) typical TeX implementation? (The fact that the error message doesn't start on a newline when redirecting to a file…)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Either way works I guess. But `\typeout` etc. has the same behavior.